# How to implement a date picker?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

What's the best way to implement/show a date picker UI in a card/widget in Gmail add-on? My use-case is showing the user's calendar events for a selected date. Any help is greatly appreciated in advance!

Comment: I don't see a dedicated input widget type available for this.. Have you already considered using drop-down selection input widgets-- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/selection-input, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/selection-input-type

Comment: I've initiated a feature request for the same at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110375285

Answer (score 2):

Custom UI isn't supported by Gmail add-ons, so to answer your question you cannot implement a date picker yet. Hope Google adds the support soon.

Instead, check this add-on sample https://github.com/googlesamples/gmail-add-ons-samples/tree/master/meeting-assistant

Also, add-ons are written using Apps Script, which is built on top of JavaScript and is a server-side language.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/